# How to split a string in a datatable and add into new rows using Linq C#?

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq

I am new to linq. I am using linq to get vlaues from datalist control and creating a datatable with that values. The datatable contains three columns. In that, sometimes the 'Answer' column is having a data which is comma separated. 
[image: You can see the image of datatable with comma separated column]

```
            DataTable SaveAnswer = clsSource.SetData();
            var df = from DataListItem dli in PollDataList.Items
                     let z = ((HiddenField)dli.FindControl("IDReqHiddenField")) 
                     let y = ((RadioButtonList)dli.FindControl("rdblstPollOptions"))
                     let v = ((CheckBoxList)dli.FindControl("CheckBoxListMultiplePollOptions"))
                     select new
                     {
                         PollId=z.Value,
                         Answered1 = y.SelectedValue,
                         Answered2=v.Items.Cast<ListItem>().Where(r=>r.Selected)
                     };
           var result = from p in df
                         select SavePollAnswer.LoadDataRow(
                            new object[] { 
                                p.PollId,p.Answered1+string.Join( ", ", p.Answered2 ),""
                            },
                            false);
            SavePollAnswer = result.CopyToDataTable();
```

And here is my design

```
<asp:DataList ID="PollDataList" runat="server"    CssClass="poll-preview">
        <ItemTemplate>
            <asp:HiddenField ID="PollIDReqHiddenField" Value='<%# Eval("PollID") %>' runat="server" Visible="false" />
            <asp:Label ID="lblReqQuestionNumber" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("NoofPollQuestion") %>' Font-Bold="true"></asp:Label><br />
            <asp:Label ID="lblRequiredPollQusetion" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("PollQuestions") %>' Font-Bold="false"></asp:Label>
            <asp:Label ID="lblReqNotification" runat="server" ForeColor="Red" CssClass='<%# Eval("PollReq") %>' Text="*" Font-Bold="true"></asp:Label>
            <asp:RadioButtonList ID="rdblstPollOptions" DataSource='<%# Eval("PollOptionsReq") %>' runat="server"></asp:RadioButtonList>
            <asp:CheckBoxList ID="CheckBoxListMultiplePollOptions" DataSource='<%# Eval("PollOptionsMul") %>'  runat="server" RepeatDirection="Vertical" RepeatColumns="1"></asp:CheckBoxList>
        </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:DataList>
```

But we want the datatable output like this 
[image: Expected Output]

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Would I be stating the obvious with [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5ycd1034(v=vs.80).aspx)? Split the ones with 2 values and add new 2 new rows.

Comment: I think I have to explain it more clearly...In the first image you can see the "PollAnswer" column having selected options(2,3) for the "PollID" (36). But the output I need should not be like this       (36->2,3).It should be 36->2,36->3(you can see in second image).

Comment: Yes, I see that. Where you build your `new object[]` you need to see if p.Answered2 is not empty/null. If not, meaning there is a comma separated value to view in separate rows, perform the first insert with a new object with p.Answered1, then again with another row and p.Answered2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

LINQ can get you partway by allowing you to nest `from` clauses in queries (simplifying the output a bit):

```
from DataListItem dli in PollDataList.Items
let z = ... // as in existing code
let y = ...
let v = ...
from checkbox in v.Items
where checkbox.Selected
select new [] { z.Value, checkbox.Value, "" }
```

Here you will get an output item for each selected checkbox in each poll item (your `Answered2`). But you also want an output row for the `Answered1` value for each poll item, and here LINQ is less helpful. There are two ways you can do this, the quick and ugly way using [Enumerable.Concat](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb302894.aspx):

```
...
let v = ...
from answer in new [] { y.SelectedValue }.Concat(v.Items.Where(r => r.Selected)) // http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb302894.aspx
select new [] { z.Value, answer, "" }
```

Or the clearer and more general, but longer way, using `yield` to create an [iterator method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9k7k7cf0.aspx) that gives you an item for all the answers:

```
from DataListItem item in PollDataList.Items
let z = ...
from answer in PollItemAnswers(item)
...
// outside the method containing the above
IEnumerable<object> PollItemAnswers(PollListItem item)
{
    var y = ...; // As in let statements
    var v = ...;
    yield return y.Value; // return the first answer
    foreach (var checkBox in v.Items)
        if (checkBox.Selected)
            yield return checkBox.Value; // return the other answers
}
```

And finally, if your final code don't have the items already separated (say, it was posted from a web form), you can use `string.Split()`:

```
 yield return y.Value;
 foreach (var answer in value.Split(',')) // "a, b, c" -> "a", " b", " c"
     yield return answer.Trim(); // " b" -> "b"
```

As a final note, watch out for if your answers could contain `,`! In general, using something like JSON to safely move value collections around (say from a file or another machine) will save you a lot of grief.

Comment: Thank you. I unable to apply your piece of code..Can you please guide me to figure this out.

Comment: @Sudha: I can't answer questions about how `DataTable`s work, but you seem to have gotten that far already. If it's not clear, `...` is where your existing code would be, I've removed what isn't required for the answer. Other than that, the only difference is that I combined the `df` and `result` queries.

Comment: @Sudha: I've made a few changes to the example code, where it wasn't clear what was being skipped as being unimportant to the answer. Perhaps I'm not understanding what `PollDataList.Items` is containing? Are you having trouble getting the results of the query into `SavePollAnswer`?

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I have added design also. PollDataList is a datalist which contains hidden field, radiobuttonlist and checkboxlist controls. While reading values from datalist, I got selected values of CheckBoxList as ListItem(Answered2). I want these values in DataTable. So when I copy query to datatable, I made list items as comma separated string. I need this not as comma separated but individual row with respective pollId.

Comment: @Sudha: Then, as near as I can tell, you have no reason to do the `string.Join(v.Items where ...)`, as you can simply `from checkbox in v.Items where ...` inside the one query and get what you are asking for - that is the first part of my answer. It's not clear how you intended your `Answer1` to work, but I made a guess that you also wanted a row for that too, and that was the rest of my answer.

Comment: Yes but when I try to implement the first part, I am getting the following error,"An expression of type 'System.Web.UI.WebControls.ListItemCollection' is not allowed in a subsequent from clause in a query expression with source type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<AnonymousType#1>'.  Type inference failed in the call to 'SelectMany'."

Comment: Ahh. That's because WebForms are terrible and old. Its why you have the type in `from DataListItem dli in PollDataList.Items` and the `.Cast<ListItem>()` - you can use `from ListItem checkbox in v.Items` or `v.Items.Cast<ListItem>()`

Comment: Thank you Simon. The first part is working fine. But to get along with radiobuttonlist selected value(Answered1), when I tried to implement **from answer in new [] { y.SelectedValue }.Concat(v.Items.Where(r => r.Selected))**, I am getting error.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/31443/discussion-between-sudha-and-simon-buchan)